# How to define scope to get one record of a has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, has-many

```
class User
    has_many :posts do
      def latest(report_date)
        order(:report_date).where('report_date <= ?', report_date).limit(1)
      end
    end
end

class Post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to retrieve the records of user with the last post for each user.

I could do this:

```
users = User.all.map{|user| user.posts.latest(7.weeks.ago).first}.compact
```

Is there a better way to write this? something like:

```
users = User.posts.latest(7.weeks.ago).all
```

if that were valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to add something like this.  Would it work in your case?  It's nice because you can 'include' it in list queries...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_one :latest_post, :class_name => 'Post', :order => 'report_date desc'

  ...

end
```

In practice, you would do something like this in the controller:

```
@users = User.include(:latest_post)
```

And then, in the view where you render the user, you could refer to user.lastest_post and it will be eager loaded.

For example - if this was in index.html.haml

```
= render @users
```

you can access latest_post in _user.html.haml

```
= user.name
= user.latest_post.report_date
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the has_one relation doesn't work with ActiveRecord.
 
    User.latest_post.all

error with undefined method 'latest_post' for #<Class:0x2e231dff>

I would have to do

    User.all.map{|x| x.latest_post}

But that would prevent me from chaining and eager loading; eg

    User.active_user.includes(:followers).latest_post.all <- 
doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the answer to include example controller and view code.